# How to change text under image

Tags: lightbox2

I don't know how to change text "Image x of y" under image in album. How can I change it?

[image]

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759499/lightbox-how-to-translate-image-x-of-x-text

Comment: Thank you, I found it :) In file \dist\js\lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js on line 37.